# Почему не обновляется nginx в Debian?

Tags: nginx, debian

В Debian buster подключил репозиторий nginx [по этим инструкциям](https://nginx.org/ru/linux_packages.html#Debian). Только вместо install пишу upgrade, т.к. nginx у меня уже установлен. Новая версия из репо подхватывается, но не устанавливается. Почему?

```
apt list --upgradable
Вывод списка… Готово
nginx/stable 1.16.1-1~buster all [может быть обновлён с: 1.14.2-2+deb10u1]
N: Есть 2 дополнительные версии. Используйте «-a» для их просмотра.

apt upgrade
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Расчёт обновлений… Готово
Следующие пакеты будут оставлены в неизменном виде:
  nginx
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 1 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Comment: Что показывает `apt-cache policy nginx` ?

Comment: Оказывается, нужно сначала снести предыдущую версию под корень. Потом ставить новую. Просто обновить с помощью upgrade не получится.